# Using selfwritten .sh file in another .sh file

Tags: bash

I am writing a small .sh program in bash.

The problem is extremely simple, i.e, to dind the primefactors of a number.
What I've done is written a .sh file to check if a number is prime or not.
Here is the code for that :

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    exit
fi
number=$1
half=$(($number / 2))
for (( i=2;i<$half;i++ ))
do
    rem=$(($number % $i))
    if [ $rem -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "0"
        exit
    fi
done
echo "1"
```

And the second .sh file to generate prime factors :

```
clear

echo "Enter number : "
read number
half=$(($number / 2))
for(( i=1;i<=$half;i++ ))
do
    rem=$(($number % $i))
    if [ $rem -eq 0 ]; then
        ok=`prime.sh $rem`
        if [ "$ok" == "1" ]; then
            echi $i
        fi 
    fi
done
```

This line ,

```
ok=`prime.sh $rem`
```

gives the following error :

```
primefactor.sh: line 10: prime.sh: command not found
```

So, is it not possible to divide a program into smaller modules and use it in the other modules like other programming languages ?
Some help on how to achieve this will be helpful.

Comment: why you just don't write this script in terms of functions ?

Comment: Because I wanted to use it as a command. The very purpose of writing this code in this way is to test out whether this is possible or not.

Comment: what do you mean with that ? In a bash script you can use functions and variables just like in any other language.

Comment: It's certainly *possible*. It's also inefficient, compared to functions.

Comment: I am not talking about functions here..

Comment: We know you aren't. The advice given is that you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your script like this:

```
ok=`./prime.sh $rem`
```

Comment: Brilliant!!Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

```
primefactor.sh: line 10: prime.sh: command not found
```

...means that `prime.sh` is not in your PATH, or is not executable. There are a few ways you can remedy this:

- First, ensure that the `+x` bit is set:

  `chmod +x prime.sh`
- ...then, add it to your PATH:

  `PATH=.:$PWD`
- ...or invoke it directly:

  `ok=$(./prime.sh)`

By the way, names ending in `.sh` are appropriate for POSIX sh **libraries**, not bash **scripts** (which typically aren't valid POSIX sh scripts anyhow). You don't run `ls.elf`; you should run `prime`, not `prime.sh`, for the same reasons.

---

That said, if your goal is just to split your code amongst multiple files, a library might be the right thing. Using subshells (which fork an existing shell instance) is much more efficient than spawning subprocesses (which involve both a fork and an exec).

For instance, you could write `prime.bash`:

```
check() {
  local number half i rem
  number=$1
  half=$((number / 2))
  for (( i=2; i<half; i++ )); do
    rem=$((number % i))
    if (( rem == 0 )); then
      echo "0"
      return
    fi
  done
  echo "1"
}
```

...and then, in your `primefactor` script, read in that library and use the function it defined:

```
source prime.bash # read in the library
clear

echo "Enter number : "
read number
half=$((number / 2))
for(( i=1;i<=half;i++ ))
do
    rem=$((number % i))
    if (( rem == 0 )); then
        ok=$(check "$rem")
        if [[ $ok = 1 ]]; then
            echo "$i"
        fi 
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description.

Comment: @Priyabrata, most welcome. You might note several other changes -- for instance, the expansion operator `$` is not needed in math contexts (`(( ))`), quotations are not needed in `[[ ]]` contexts, the POSIX-compliant comparison operator is `=` not `==` (although bash allows either), etc.

Comment: Nice answer. I was lucky to guess his problem ;-) But from my experience this is the most common problem.